# Dynamically created row not showing after for loop

Tags: php, html, for-loop, html-table

I have a form where I can subscribe users to newsletters which looks like this:

[image]

And the code for it is this:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;  
while($objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1))  
 {  
$i++;  
?>  
<tr>  
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["ID"];?><input type="hidden" name="mailid[]" value="<?=$objResult1["ID"];?>"> </div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Titel"];?> </div></td>  
   <td><div align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="sub[]" value="10"> </div></td>  
   <td><div align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="sub[]" value="90"> </div></td>
</tr>  
<?php  
 }  
?>
```

The $objQuery1:

```
$strSQL1        = "SELECT ID, Titel FROM Mail";
$objQuery1  = mysql_query($strSQL1);
```

This form works just fine like this, the problem is that I wanted to change the input to radio. For this I edited it to the following:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;  
while($objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1))  
{  
$i++;  
?>  
<?php for ($i = 0; $objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1); $i++) : ?>
<tr>  
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["ID"];?><input type="hidden" name="mailid[]" value="<?=$objResult1["ID"];?>"> </div></td>
   <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Titel"];?> </div></td>  
   <td><div align="center"><input type="radio" name="sub[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="10"> </div></td>  
   <td><div align="center"><input type="radio" name="sub[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="90">  </div></td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
    <?php  
}  
?>
```

The problem with this is that now the first row with the ID 1 is no longer displayed. Does anyone know what went wrong?^^ It probably is a quite simple solution but I can't seem to find it. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nested two loops: while and for. Both seem to do the same work (ie: fetching rows from result set). So basically your first `while` "consume" your first row. You should get rid of it.

Comment: Thnx, this actually worked^^ As I said it is a simple solution but I just didn't see it. I will accept your answer when I am able to!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `$objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1)`, you fetch one row from the result set. So when you do this, right after it:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1); $i++): ?>
```

You're fetching the second row of the result set, and that's what you're using in `$objResult1`. In your code, you never use the first result set.

My suggestion if you have to keep this design is to use a `do{} while();` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1); $i++) : ?>
```

to

```
<?php for ($j = 0; $objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1); $j++) : ?>
```

And the content inside the loop accrodingly

You are getting mixed up by using the $i in the outer and inner loop

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the for-loop.  Just change the check boxes to radio buttons in your while-loop.

EDIT:

```
<?php 
$i = 1;  

while($objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1)) {  
    $i++;  
?>  
<tr>  
    <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["ID"];?><input type="hidden" name="mailid[]" value="<?=$objResult1["ID"];?>"> </div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult1["Titel"];?> </div></td>  
    <td><div align="center"><input type="radio" name="sub[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="10"> </div></td>  
    <td><div align="center"><input type="radio" name="sub[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="90"> </div></td>
</tr>  
<?php  
}  
?>
```

Comment: When I do that all the radio buttons will have the same name and I wont be able to select 1 on each row.